# What's the best way to handle Netty async task to http request?

Tags: java, netty, backend, rocketmq

I've encountered some problem when build a IoT service.

My architecture is shown as below:

```
UserBrowser<------>WebServer<---->NettyServer<----->Client(IoT device, auto response)
```

Here netty server act as a passthrough proxy which convert `Userbrowser` message and web server message to binary stream to remote IoT device, and then IoT device return back some message to user.

I use `RocketMQ` to communicate between `WebServer` and `NettyServer`

My question is since http request  of UserBrowser is a **sync** operation, Netty is a async architecture, how to convert an async operation in Netty  to sync HTTP request ?

Should I cache the requests and wait for response from IoT , and then return back? in this situation `WebServer` is  a sync call

Or should I use async always, the UserBrowser poll result from `WebServer`  ?

Comment: You have a couple options here. Either you can block the web request until you've asynchronously completed a result from the IoT device (`CompletableFuture` is very nice for this), or you can add support in your protocol for a later/separate response object. I'm personally a fan of the latter but it can depend on the hardware in use. Opinion-wise I feel blocking for something widely used doesn't scale as well.

Comment: `My protocol` you mean the protocol between `NettyServer` and `IoT device`? this channel runs a standard protocol that doesn't allowed to be modified